# Windows 8 Graphics Display Issues

Tags: windows, windows-8, display

I installed windows 8, updated the graphics driver:
**Product:** `GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a`
**Driver:** `307.74`

Every once in a while the screen will display horizontal lines like this:

[image: Graphics]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Try diagnosing it step by step. If it did not happen before you updated the graphics drivers, revert to the old one. Then check if it still happens with the old ones. Try a live CD or an other OS (and thus other drivers). Does it still happen. If it does then the driver update might be a coincidence. If it does not start abinary search between working and problem driver versions.

Comment: It was happening before I updated the driver, so I updated the driver hoping it would fix it. It didn't.

Comment: In that case it might be a hardware problem. How hot does the chip get? (use GPU-Z or similar to check). When was the last time you cleaned the computer? Is there a lot of dust on the heatsink?

Comment: I rebuilt the computer in December, and vacuumed out all the dust before I put the new parts in. It is currently using the MOBO's chip set. I think I have an old graphics card laying around that might be better than the built in chip set.

Comment: look in the nVIDIA driver option if you have an option FXAA. Disable this setting.